# How to prevent the duplication of `RecyclerView` when scrolling?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am showing a love sign on my `RecyclerView`.
When user clicked the color of the love sign changes from default gray to red color but when I scrolled it is showing color in some other positions(not clicked). Also the clicked color changes to gray.

I found large number of solutions but nothing worked for me.
Please help.
I am giving you my codes

**Featured Products class**

```
public class FeaturedlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturedlistAdapter.FeaturedView>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<Featured_data> featured_data;

    public FeaturedlistAdapter(Context context, List<Featured_data> featured_data,MyAdapterListener  myAdapterListener) {
        this.context=context;
        this.featured_data=featured_data;
        this.onclickListener=myAdapterListener;

    }

@NonNull
@Override
public FeaturedView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_allbrands, viewGroup, false);
    return new FeaturedView(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeaturedView featuredView, int i) {

    String price = featured_data.get(i).getProductPrice();
    String name = featured_data.get(i).getProductName();
    String quantity = featured_data.get(i).getProductQty();
    featuredView.getTxt_brandname().setText(featured_data.get(i).getProductName());
    String wishlist=featured_data.get(i).getWishlist();
    Picasso.get().load(HomeConstants.BASE_URL + featured_data.get(i).getProductImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.whitebackground).into(featuredView.img_brand);
    if (price != null && !price.equals("")) {
        String total_price = price + " Rs";
        featuredView.getTxt_brand_price().setText(total_price);
    }
    if (quantity != null && !quantity.equals("")) {
        String total_quantity = quantity + " Items";
        featuredView.getTxt_brand_item().setText(total_quantity);
    }
    if(wishlist!=null)
    {
        if(wishlist.equals("0"))
        {
            featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 211, 211, 211));
            featuredView.txt_count.setText("0");
        }
        else if(wishlist.equals("1"))
        {
            featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,255,0,0));
            featuredView.txt_count.setText("1");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 211, 211, 211));
        featuredView.txt_count.setText("0");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return featured_data.size();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

class FeaturedView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView img_brand,img_wishlist;
    TextView txt_brandname,txt_brand_price,txt_brand_item,txt_count;

    public ImageView getImg_brand() {
        return img_brand;
    }

    public ImageView getImg_wishlist() {
        return img_wishlist;
    }

    public TextView getTxt_brandname() {
        return txt_brandname;
    }

    public TextView getTxt_brand_price() {
        return txt_brand_price;
    }

    public TextView getTxt_brand_item() {
        return txt_brand_item;
    }

    public TextView getTxt_count() {
        return txt_count;
    }

    FeaturedView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img_brand=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_brand);
        img_wishlist=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_wishlist);
        txt_brandname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brandname);
        txt_brand_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brand_price);
        txt_brand_item=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brand_item);
        txt_count=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);
        img_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String value = txt_count.getText().toString();
                if (value.equals("0")) {
                    img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                    txt_count.setText("1");

                } else if (value.equals("1")) {
                    img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 211, 211, 211));
                    txt_count.setText("0");

                }
                onclickListener.wishlistOnclick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        img_brand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onclickListener.brandOnClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}

private MyAdapterListener onclickListener;

public interface MyAdapterListener
{
    void wishlistOnclick(View view ,int position);
    void brandOnClick(View view,int position);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the state of the view by using [SparseBooleanArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray). It is because in `RecylerView` the item will be shown with the previous view (if exist), i.e the view will be recycled first before used. Hence the mean of RecyclerView.

You can do something like this:

**First**, in your Adapter, add the SparseBooleanArray to hold the flags (Please read the comment in the code):

```
public class FeaturedlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturedlistAdapter.FeaturedView>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<Featured_data> featuredData;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedFlags;

    public FeaturedlistAdapter(Context context, List<Featured_data> featured_data,MyAdapterListener  myAdapterListener) {
        ...

        // init the flag
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeaturedView featuredView, int i) {
       int position = featuredView.getAdapterPosition();
       Featured_data data = featuredData.get(position);

       // reset the state of the view each time the 
       // view get recycled by applying the flag.
       if(mSelectedFlags.get(position)) {
          // set the selected state, i.e red
       } else {
          // SparseBooleanArray.get(i) is false if not found
          // set the unselected state, i.e grey
       }
}
```

**then** in your `ViewHolder`, set the state when member view is clicked/selected:

```
class FeaturedView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ...

    FeaturedView(@NonNull View itemView) {
        ...
        img_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              ...
              // save the selected state
              mSparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);

            }
         ...
    }
}
```

Now the view selected/unselected state will be reset using the saved stated from your SparseBooleanArray flag holder.

Comment: Thank you ..Thank you.Finally I made it. I will submit the full code.Hope it will be useful to other people .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace Following Code in your file and try

```
       if(wishlist!=null)
        {
            if(wishlist.equals("1"))   // change is here
            {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb((255,255,0,0));
                featuredView.txt_count.setText("1");
            }
            else (wishlist.equals("0"))   // change is here
            {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,255,111,111));
                featuredView.txt_count.setText("0");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 211, 211, 211));
            featuredView.txt_count.setText("0");
        }
```

Also for this

```
    img_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                featured_data.get(getAdapterPosition).setWishlist(featured_data.get(getAdapterPosition).getWishlist().equals("0")?"1":"0");
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                    onclickListener.wishlistOnclick(v,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Actually i am saving 0 as a default count.When user clicked the txt_count changes to 1 and also sending status to server.When user clicked again,the color of love sign changes to gray color and also sever value is changed...

Comment: Yes I got that, So in updated answer check that I had reversed that condition of yours. So red color will only be there if wishlist is 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FeaturedlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturedlistAdapter.FeaturedView>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<Featured_data> featured_data;

    private final SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;


    public FeaturedlistAdapter(Context context, List<Featured_data> featured_data,MyAdapterListener  myAdapterListener) {
        this.context=context;
        this.featured_data=featured_data;
        this.onclickListener=myAdapterListener;
        // init the flag
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FeaturedView onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_allbrands, viewGroup, false);
        return new FeaturedView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeaturedView featuredView, int i) {

        String price = featured_data.get(i).getProductPrice();
        String name = featured_data.get(i).getProductName();
        String quantity = featured_data.get(i).getProductQty();
        featuredView.getTxt_brandname().setText(featured_data.get(i).getProductName());
        String wishlist=featured_data.get(i).getWishlist();
        Picasso.get().load(HomeConstants.BASE_URL + featured_data.get(i).getProductImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.whitebackground).into(featuredView.img_brand);
        if (price != null && !price.equals("")) {
            String total_price = price + " Rs";
            featuredView.getTxt_brand_price().setText(total_price);
        }
        if (quantity != null && !quantity.equals("")) {
            String total_quantity = quantity + " Items";
            featuredView.getTxt_brand_item().setText(total_quantity);
        }


        if(wishlist!=null)
        {
            if(wishlist.equals("0"))
            {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 211, 211, 211));
                featuredView.txt_count.setText("0");
            }
            else if(wishlist.equals("1"))
            {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,255,0,0));
                featuredView.txt_count.setText("1");
            }
        }
        int position=featuredView.getAdapterPosition();
        if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position))
        {
            String value = featuredView.txt_count.getText().toString();
            if (value.equals("0")) {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));

                // save the selected state
            }
            else if (value.equals("1")) {
                featuredView.img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,211,211,211));
                // save the selected state
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return featured_data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    class FeaturedView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView img_brand,img_wishlist;
        TextView txt_brandname,txt_brand_price,txt_brand_item,txt_count;

        public ImageView getImg_brand() {
            return img_brand;
        }

        public ImageView getImg_wishlist() {
            return img_wishlist;
        }

        public TextView getTxt_brandname() {
            return txt_brandname;
        }

        public TextView getTxt_brand_price() {
            return txt_brand_price;
        }

        public TextView getTxt_brand_item() {
            return txt_brand_item;
        }

        public TextView getTxt_count() {
            return txt_count;
        }

        FeaturedView(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_brand=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_brand);
            img_wishlist=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_wishlist);
            txt_brandname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brandname);
            txt_brand_price=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brand_price);
            txt_brand_item=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_brand_item);
            txt_count=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);
            img_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value = txt_count.getText().toString();
                    if (value.equals("0")) {
                        img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
                        txt_count.setText("1");

                    } else if (value.equals("1")) {
                        img_wishlist.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,211,211,211));
                        txt_count.setText("0");


                    }
                    onclickListener.wishlistOnclick(v,getAdapterPosition());
                    mSparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
            img_brand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onclickListener.brandOnClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private MyAdapterListener onclickListener;

    public interface MyAdapterListener
    {
        void wishlistOnclick(View view ,int position);
        void brandOnClick(View view,int position);
    }
}
```